# What is the advantage to inferred types *in Swift*?

Tags: type-systems, swift-language

As I fool around in Swift I have come to absolutely hate variable declarations. `int c = 0` seems easier to read than `var c:Int = 0` and more informative than `var c = 0`, and `int some()` is radically better than `func some() -> Int`.

As has been pointed out in other threads, the reason for the type at the end is that the type is then optional, which in turn is due to type inference. And I can see some cases where type inference is useful in other languages, especially ones without the powerful protocol extensibility found in Swift.

When I examine what's out on the 'net discussing this, it's always using examples in languages that did not offer type anonymity, like [this one aimed at C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing/). Those that do discuss Swift are always pointing out it's problems, like [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316217/why-does-the-type-go-after-the-variable-name-in-modern-programming-languages) or [this](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/08/12/clean-coding-in-swift-type-inference/).

So... what is the advantage of type inference **in Swift**?

Comment: Clearly, if it's just an `int`, you would declare an `int` and not bother with the var.  But if your type was `ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string,SomeVeryLongTypeName>>`, you'd be *very* glad to not have to say that twice in the same statement.

Comment: In any case, the advantages of type inference in Swift are the same as the advantages of type inference in any other language.  I don't see Swift as particularly special in that regard.

Comment: How is var c:Int = 0 more informative than var c = 0 ?
They both convey the exact same information. That its a non boxed Int of value 0. 
As for your second example, isn't this just a syntax preference? Different languages, different syntax. No better, no worse, just different.

Comment: @RobertHarvey- are you familiar with the loose typing in Obj-C that addressed many of the advantages pointed out in the other threads?

Comment: @Shayne - because the former example is self-documenting and can be read by anyone, while the later is only understood by the compiler.

Comment: Uh no? Its obviously as readable. And its weird that you think it isn't. Theres no ambiguity in its meaning

Comment: For Swift specifically, one of the big design decisions was to try to make it friendly to beginning programmers. words like `var` and `func` are redundant to experienced programmers, but for beginners these make it read a lot more like English. But if you want this beginner-friendly style to be compiled fast, your only real choice is type inference.