# Is it true that variable type before name makes compiler work easier?

Tags: programming-languages, c, compiler

I have seen information that at least one of reasons why type placed before variable name is that it allows compiler easier evaluate size and type of variable. If so then how (what way) it eases this work?

Comment: you mean like when people write `int iPosition;` instead of `int position;`? Or do you mean `int position;` instead of `var position : int;` like it is in other languages?

Comment: @user253751 iPosition is a name. The 2nd.

Comment: This feature causes *problems* in C language parsing so I'd say it's complete BS. Consider whether `a * b;` is a multiplication or a variable declaration.

Comment: Specifically, I think you are asking if it makes it easier to parse.

Comment: @JimmyJames I think so

Comment: this matter was discussed in depth already, see eg [Why does the type go after the variable name in modern programming languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/316217/31260) and it linked questions

Comment: C++ says that if `a*b;` can be interpreted both as a valid declaration and a valid statement, then it is a declaration.  So, the compiler is invited to try both ways (as declaration then as statement), in case the first fails.

Answer (score 3):

There are various tradeoffs in the difficulty of parsing.

Language parsers are usually designed to work left-to-right, top-to-bottom. Syntax like `var x : int;` is very simple to parse because as soon as the compiler reads the first word `var` it knows it should parse the line as a variable declaration and not something else.

`int x;` also works because as soon as the compiler reads `int` it knows this is a variable declaration. However, consider user-defined types: `a * b;` could be a declaration for `b` with type `a *` or it could multiply the variables `a` and `b`. The parser doesn't know just by reading the word `a`. Depending on the language design, at best it just has to look at whether `a` is a type or a variable; at worst it has to try both ways and see which one works.

Even the first option isn't ideal. The *compiler* has no problem knowing whether `a` is a type or a variable. But consider all the other programs that might have to parse code - IDEs, documentation generators. Now they have to find all the type and variable names so they can see whether `a` is a type or a variable, and sometimes they'll get it wrong (I'm looking at you, *include paths*). Whereas your IDE can very easily see that `var b : a*;` declares a variable called `b`, no matter what.

But that problem is also the fault of the `*` symbol, which means either multiplication or pointer type. If you say that `^^` means a pointer type, then you don't have to know what `a` is to know that `a b;` is a declaration, `a * b;` is multiplication and `a ^^ b;` is a declaration. The parser is still a little more complex, because it has to read the whole line to work out whether it's a declaration, not just the first word, but that's manageable.

Variable declarations in C are designed with the principle of "declaration follows use" - that is to say, the declaration looks like how the variable is used. `int x;` means `x` is an `int`. `int * x;` is often thought to mean `x` is an `int *`, but that is incorrect according to the principle - it actually means that `* x` is an `int`. `int (*x)[5];` means that `(*x)[0 up to 4]` is an `int`, and so on. They didn't have to be designed this way and other languages design them differently.